# How to refresh modal page after a put request?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a modal page which shows some tournament matches on the view. And, there is also a button which is using for updating the scores of the matches. However, I need to reload the page to fetch new scores from the server and demonstrate them on the screen. However, I couldn't figure out how to do this.

The following is the function that I fetched the updated scores;

```
getMatches() {
    this.http.get(this.MATCHES_URL, { headers: this.contentHeader })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.matches = data;
      },
      err => alert(err),
    );
  }
```

Where can I call it to update the scores on the screen? Please don't say me window.location.reload(). That is not what I am looking for :)

HTML content;

```
<ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="matches.length <= 0"><br>
    <h3>Tournament is not scheduled yet!!</h3>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="matches !== undefined">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-list-header>
        Round 1
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let match of matches">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col class="team_home">
              <div>
                <img class="home_logo" [src]="match.team_a.logo">
                <h2>{{match.team_a.team_name}}</h2>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <div *ngIf="match.match_status ==='Finished'" class="score">
                <h1>{{match.team_a_score}}-{{match.team_b_score}}</h1>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="match.match_status==='Not Started'" class="score">
                <h1>VS</h1>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col class="team_visitor">
              <div>
                <img class="visitor_logo" [src]="match.team_b.logo">
                <h2>{{match.team_b.team_name}}</h2>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
        <div *ngIf="username === tournament.creator[0]">
          <button ion-button clear (click)="enterScores(match.id,match.team_a, match.team_b)" color="danger" icon-left>
      <ion-icon name='stats'></ion-icon>
          Enter Scores
        </button>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Functions that I am using to update the scores;

```
updateScore(id, team_a_score, team_b_score) {
    this.UPDATE_SCORE_URL = this.UPDATE_SCORE_URL + id + "/";
    console.log(this.UPDATE_SCORE_URL);
    let params = {
      match_status: 'Finished',
      team_a_score: +team_a_score,
      team_b_score: +team_b_score
    }


    this.http.put(this.UPDATE_SCORE_URL, JSON.stringify(params), { headers: this.contentHeader })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
      data => console.log("adding success"),
      err => alert(err),
    );
  }

  enterScores(id, team_a, team_b) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Update Scores',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'team_a_score',
          placeholder: team_a.team_name
        },
        {
          name: 'team_b_score',
          placeholder: team_b.team_name,
          type: 'number'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Update',
          handler: data => {
            this.updateScore(id, data.team_a_score, data.team_b_score);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but are you calling `getMatches()` after making changes?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Angular detects if you update the data and redraws the view automatically.

So to update you just need to update the data that the view uses to draw itself.

Comment: So, it is not a general case because it is not redrawing

Comment: You should also post the code you use to draw the data. Probably there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I posted them please check and thank you for your help

Comment: by the way when I change the matches array manually, the view changes automatically, however when I change it with a request it isn't changing

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are using Angular I don't think reloading the page is a good idea, that's the whole point of Angular (serving single page applications). What I would suggest is to use property binding or string interpolation for the matches variable so if you wanted to display all scores in separate paragraphs you can do something like this in your template:

```
<p *ngFor="let match of matches">{{ match.score }}</p>
```

This is string interpolation and will create a paragraph HTML element for each of your matches

Comment: Can you post your template code that does that and also the typescript code for matches? The other thing I can think of is that data might not be the correct type (Match[] for example)

Comment: I posted them please check and thank you for your help

Comment: by the way when I change the matches array manually, the view changes automatically, however when I change it with a request it isn't changing

Comment: Yeah that's what I expected. I think you need to make sure that this assignment is correct:
`this.matches = data;`
and that data is an object that can be stored as the type of your matches variable. If data contains a parent object like this:
`{
    "data": [...]
}`
then you need to reference that (data.data I think). Try printing data to the console first

Comment: How can it be wrong, when the page is rendering for the first time I am using the same request and same array

Comment: Sorry just edited my previous post (I pressed enter and posted before completing my answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149321/discussion-between-cano-and-mousi).